# Element 'foo': This element is not expected". Expected is one of ( {url}foo, {url}bar )

Tags: php, xml, xsd

When validating an XML DOMDocument with a scheme:

> $result = $Document -> schemaValidate('../../DTE/document/scheme.xsd');

I get a warning message like:

Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element 'foo': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {url}foo, {url}bar ).

What is the difference between 'foo' and '{url}foo' and how to fix this warning?

Comment: Literally `{url}`, or are you just using a wrong (default) namespace and there's actually an uri there?

Comment: none of these, it actualy represents a correct namespace

Comment: If it's the namespace, I'd still say the namespace of your `foo` node doesn't match the required namespace. Beware of small typos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation `{url}foo` is used to refer to an expanded name whose namespace part is `url` and whose local name part is `foo`.  It's sometimes referred to as 'Clark notation' for James Clark, who promoted it.  When this notation is in use, unqualified names are sometimes referred to using the notation `{}foo` and sometimes (as in your error message) using the notation `foo`.

The error message is telling you that it has found an element with the unqualified name `foo`, at a location where it was expecting a namespace-qualfied element named either `foo` or `bar` in the namespace `url`.  Probable cause:  the XML instance lacks a required namespace declaration.